# How to get data from MySQL using prisma

Tags: mysql, prisma

I have a database stored in MySQL, and I am reading this documentation in how to get this data using prisma:

https://www.prisma.io/docs/getting-started/setup-prisma/start-from-scratch/relational-databases/connect-your-database-node-mysql

However, what I don't understand is how to get a specific table.

For example my data base is called "mydb" and I have 2 tables inside named "example1" and "example2". So if I want to get the data from "example1" table how do I do that? Because the way that I understand from the documentation is connecting with my database but how do I connect with my table? What should I add in the URL?

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://johndoe:XXX@mysql–instance1.123456789012.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/mydb"
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot connect to a specific table through a connection string.
You can connect to a specific schema in the database though.

If you want to get data from specific tables you would need to generate `PrismaClient` and access the data through queries.

To generate Prisma Client, you would need to invoke

```
npx prisma generate
```

Here's an example query to get all data from example1 table:

```js
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

async function main() {

  const allData = await prisma.example1.findMany({
    where: {},
  });

  console.log('allData', allData);
}

main()
  .catch((e) => {
    throw e;
  })
  .finally(async () => {
    await prisma.$disconnect();
  });
```

This [guide](https://www.prisma.io/docs/getting-started/quickstart) should be helpful to you.